# Sublime text 2 : highlight/color a line by plugin

Tags: python, plugins, sublimetext2

I'm trying to create a plugin where i need do *colorize/highlight* a full line (not text).

For example if i do something like:

```
 for region in self.view.sel():
        if region.empty():
            line = self.view.line(region)
            self.view.add_regions('put-some-bg-color', [line], 'keyword', 'bookmark', sublime.DRAW_OUTLINED)
```

this will only put a *outline* on text until the newline char (\n).

I would like to put a backgroud color one the whole line, like it's done by the "**highlight_line**" preference.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found that this is not possible for the moment, on the [sublimetext forum response](http://www.sublimetext.com/forum/viewtopic.php?f=2&t=2256&hilit=highlight%20line&start=10#p10129), answered by site administrator for [question](http://www.sublimetext.com/forum/viewtopic.php?f=2&t=2256#p10112).

Answer (score 1):

It is possible. You should be able to draw a line like this:

```
region = view.text_point(line_number, 0)
line = self.view.line(region)
self.view.add_regions(...)
```

You can take a look at the plugin [Diffy](https://github.com/zsong/diffy) I created.